# Best way to set a Node/Express app to live or production mode

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently in the process of making my node/express app into a production deployment, and as part of this, I need to make it run in a production friendly mode (e.g. fewer debugs to stdOut, write logs to different places, tell users less when errors occur etc.).

I'm struggling a bit with this, as whenever I set a variable of virtually any kind to invoke a 'production' mode, it doesn't take affect for the program as it runs.

When launched in dev mode, my code runs through Gulp, and runs this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('ascema');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Which, as you know, is just the generated launch script from the express generator.

In order to run it in live mode, I created an alternative startup for the server to use (I could hardly use gulp anyway) and live.js runs this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var app = require('./app.js');

app.set('env', 'production');

console.log('running on Port 3000');

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

But, when I use `app.get('env')` anywhere in the app (e.g. in app.js or in it's various dependencies) it still returns 'development' and so none of my production tasks happen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to set the `NODE_ENV` variable on the command line when you execute your NodeJS application.

For example:

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

Also, `NODE_ENV` is an environment variable so if set it in the environment on your server, you will not need to provide it every time you execute your application so `node app.js` will do.

You can set your environment variables in the `/etc/environment` file. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) are more details on that.

Answer (score 11):

By using NPM you might to be used the follow scripts in the package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "dev_win": "set NODE_ENV=development && node ./bin/www >> /romba/log/api.log 2>> /romba/log/error.log",
    "prod_win": "set NODE_ENV=production && node ./bin/www >> /romba/log/api.log 2>> /romba/log/error.log"
    "prod_nix": "NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www >> /romba/log/api.log 2>> /romba/log/_error.log"
  },...
```

To start one of the script use the command:

```
 npm run-script prod_win
```

In the JavaScript code I check the condition:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.indexOf('production') > -1
```

or with Express.js

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? ...
```

Comment: I had to remove the whitespace in script as follows `set NODE_ENV=development&&node ./bin/www` because it was included in the variable and caused some problems when comparing using ===